# VBA MSXML2 Open member POST

Tags: excel, vba

In this code snipet example...

```
Dim pullSite As String
Dim pullXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set pullXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

pullSite = "http://www.ThisIsASite.com/Documents/whatever........xml"

pullXMLHTTP.Open "POST", strXMLSite, False
```

...I am confronted with the word Open in the code which I reckon is a method since it's not being equaled to anything (in the OB screen at the bottom left once picked it says it's a Sub, but I rest my case on OB naming methods as Sub and Function- I guess it wants to say this is a class browser so we state the method as Sub or Function just like when we "custom" make them in a class module but I am not sure of that). If I go to the Object Browser in the MSXML2 Library I will find in XMLHTTP the Open listed as a Member.

Well if I hit F1 VBA's help has 3 choices. First choice (VBA Library) one tells me it is the Open Statement which clearly isn't.

The Second choice (Excel Library) has an *RecentFile*.Open Method **without** parameters so it doesn't buy that either.

The Third choice (Office Library) gives me the Developer Reference main menu.

So F1 VBA's Auto help has nothing for the MSXML2 Library. However in the OB's lower left bottom if I choose from the MSXML2.XMLHTTP Library the Open Member it states

```
Sub open(bstrMethod As String, bstrUrl As String, [varAsync], [bstrUser], [bstrPassword])
    Member of MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Open HTTP connection
```

---

So my question is twofold

- Is there a solid help which documents the members of the MSXML2 Library in detail/or a way to add that on the VBA' s Autohelp? (BTW Microsoft's Development Center on MSXML [MSXLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is vast and to vague. I also believe that it points to experienced innuendos...
- **Why** do I see in relevant examples where the MSXML2.HTTP Open member is used, the first String parameter **always** populated with the word "POST" in Cap letters? It's mind boggling to me-can't they use another String value?

After @codeape 's submitted answer:

Dear codeape so according to you answer, we have the

```
open Method (IXMLHTTPRequest)
```

and the parameters in an existing VBA example (which MS lacks) *all-together* form the IXMLHTTPRequest so:

```
Open methods Paramenters --> IXMLHTTPRequest
```

Please confirm if this is true so that I will edit this post in a more user-friendly all confirmed instructions for others to use.

Also I can't help my curiosity why do we have an **I** in the IXMLHTTPRequest naming? Just wondering...

In regards to the POST Question *thanks to your answer* I googled HTTP Method and found this neat link in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) which to quite an extent explains to me. Really why not use GET? It looks more fast-forward... instead of submitting data to be processed by a specified source (with POST) just request the data from the specified source in one stroke it looks more swift and simple...

---

Oooups I almost forgot in the open Method link you gave me as well as in the bottom of OB we see bstrMethod As String, bstrUrl As String etc. Could you tell me what that *bstr* means? - Is the BSTR means Basic String or Binary String? please confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The documentation for XMLHTTP is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note that the documentation page is for the interface IXMLHTTPRequest. MSXML.XMLHTTP implements this interface.
2. The [Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method's first argument is the HTTP method, i.e. GET or POST (or PUT, DELETE, etc.).

Sadly it looks as if MS has forgotten about VBA when it comes to documenting various COM libraries. Most/all documentation is for C++ and javascript.

Comments on other things mentioned in the question:

- The "I" in IXMLHTTPRequest is a naming convention in COM used for naming interfaces.
- Regarding HTTP methods (GET, POST etc.):

  - The server-side code decides how to interpret and respond to the HTTP requests.
  - When you type a URL into you browser's URL bar, the browser sends a GET request to the server. So if you want to fetch a web page using MSXML.XMLHTTP you do: `obj.Open "GET", "http://www.google.com"`
  - When you submit a HTML form from your browser, the browser can either send a GET or a POST request depending on method attribute of the `<form>` tag. `<form method="GET">` (the default) or `<form method="POST">`.
  - Javascript on the page can send AJAX requests using XMLHTTPRequest with any HTTP method.
- Regarding argument names `bstrMethod` etc.: This is [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), where an argument's expected type is reflected in the argument's name to make things easier for the developer. The `bstr` means that this argument is a COM "[basic string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". A basic string is what COM typically uses for unicode strings. In VBA, you can use normal VBA strings where a method expects a bstr.

Comment: I am currently searching accordingly to your answer. I will submit any issue soon

Comment: Dear @codeape i have re-edited my question since following your directions

Comment: Sir thank you for your kind (and hugely intuitive) help!