# Convert GET parameter to POST request body and extract specific JSON property

Tags: json, excel, web-services, post, libreoffice-calc

### Background

- I am making a spreadsheet that refers to information security license registration provided by the Japanese government (https://riss.ipa.go.jp/). The spreadsheet will be used on Microsoft Excel/LibreOffice Calc on Windows/Linux, so I want to avoid using platform-specific functionality like a script with the `XMLHTTP60` module.
- The site https://riss.ipa.go.jp has a URI that can retrieve registration information with a registration number (https://riss.ipa.go.jp/ajax/findRissRequest). The URI only works with a POST request with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` style request body and doesn't work with a GET request. The response of the URI is JSON format.

### Problem #1

Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc have the `WEBSERVICE` function that can be used to send a request to a URI. This function is supported on all platforms and is suitable for my use case.

Unfortunately, the `WEBSERVICE` function only supports GET requests, and the URI I want to use only supports POST requests.

### Problem #2

Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc have the `FILTERXML` function that can be used to extract a specific element from XML.

Unfortunately, the URI I want to use returns response in JSON format. There are no functions to parse JSON in Microsoft Excel and LibreOffice Calc.

### Question

Is there any way to convert GET request to POST request and extract a JSON property?

For example, is there any Web API like `http://api.example.com/convert/get-to-post?uri=https://riss.ipa.go.jp/ajax/findRissRequest&reg_no=000006&property=result.reg_date` that calls https://riss.ipa.go.jp/ajax/findRissRequest with POST request body `reg_no=000006` and extract property `result.reg_date` from its response?

Comment: Excel does not have built-in capability to extract a JSON element.  There are VBA routines but that may not be appropriate for your use.  You may be able to write string functions. Also, you may run into problems with `WEBSERVICE` if the length of the returned string is greater than `32,767` (maximum length of a formula).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52903455/8112776) is also using a `GET` but it can be easily changed to `POST`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21675040/8112776). There are also several existing questions/amswers about handling JSON in VBA, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/8112776) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2782076/8112776).

Comment: @ashleedawg Wouldn't that link require the XMLHTTP module?

Comment: Yeah; it's built in, and a reference is easily added. I use it often.  (Did I miss something?)  Another option is [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/office/import-data-from-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) via Excel

Comment: @ashleedawg  The OP wrote "*I want to avoid using platform-specific functionality like a script with the XMLHTTP60 module.*"

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` doesn't work in the Linux+LibreOffice environment, so I am struggling to find some workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I could not find any existing services. So I made a web API service with AWS Lambda and API Gateway.

First, I made a Lambda function like this:

```py
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    queryStringParameters = event.get('params').get('querystring')
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(queryStringParameters)
    data = data.encode('UTF-8')

    f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://riss.ipa.go.jp/ajax/findRissRequest", data)
    j = json.loads(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
    return j
```

Then I made a resource with a GET method in API Gateway and connect it with the Lambda function.

- In Integration Request, you have to use **non-proxy** integration. Also, you have to specify a mapping template for Content-Type `application/json` with `Method Request passthrough` template.
- In Integration Response, you have to specify a mapping template for Content-Type `application/xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
#set($root = $input.path('$.result[0]'))
<result>
#foreach($key in $root.keySet())
    <$key>$root.get($key)</$key>
#end
</result>
```

Then I added the HEAD and OPTIONS method for the resource. It is because [the `WEBSERVICE` function of LibreOffice sends OPTIONS and HEAD requests before a GET request](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/webservice-returns-value-from-valid-url/77220/3).
You can use a mock in Integration Request with a mapping template for Content-Type `application/json` like `{ "statusCode": 200 }`.
The result of `WEBSERVICE` function will be `#VALUE!` without these methods.

Finally, I can get a property from a web service that only accepts POST requests and returns a JSON with `WEBSERVICE` and `FILTERXML` like:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/passthru?reg_no=000006"),"//result/reg_date")
```